# How to use thumbnail and arrows in jsssor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

So I am using jossor for a slider but I don't know why it is working wired. If I am using thumbnail the arrows are not working. If I am using arrows the thumbnail is not working. The following code I am using.

```
jssor_slider1 = function (containerId) {
        var options = {
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                 
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 
                $Steps: 1                                 
            },
            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,             
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                              

                $SpacingX: 23,                                  
                $SpacingY: 23,                                   
                $DisplayPieces: 15                              

            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
    };
```

Well this code should to let me use both. But is working only thumbnail. If I am using the following code the arrows are working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $DragOrientation: 3,
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 
                $Steps: 1                                   
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    });
```

Comment: just wondering y everything starts with a `$`??

Comment: Because is their example and all I try to do is to work with their's one

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the same problem?

Comment: OK I will try but to create for both